# C# Load Dictionary from XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an XML file that looks like:

```
<Cities>
    <Name>Seattle</Name>
    <State>WA</State>
    <Population>552105</Population>
</Cities>
```

I want to load the city info into a dictionary, so that my dictionary looks like:

```
cityDictionary("Name") = "Seattle"
cityDictionary("State") = "WA"
cityDictionary("Population") = "552105"
```

The following code does work:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(@"..\..\Cities.xml");
var rootNodes = doc.Root.DescendantNodes().OfType<XElement>();
var keyValuePairs = from n in rootNodes
                    select new
                    {
                        TagName = n.Name,
                        TagValue = n.Value
                    };

Dicitionary<string, string> allItems = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var token in keyValuePairs) {
    allItems.Add(token.TagName.ToString(), token.TagValue.ToString());
}
```

But I want to do this one step.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you just refactor your working code into a method?

Comment: Why do you want to do it in one expression? (I assume you mean "expression" when you say "step"?)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why so complex? Here is how you could do it in method chain syntax:

```
var allItems = rootNodes.ToDictionary(n => n.Name.ToString(), n => n.Value);
```

or just as a plain old loop, if you need to use an older version of C# or would like to keep things old-fashioned:

```
var allItems = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var node in rootNodes)
{
    allItems.Add(node.Name.ToString(), node.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this using [`ToDictionary.`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657.aspx)

```
    Dictionary<string, string> allItems = rootNodes.ToDictionary(v => v.Name, v => v.Value);
```

Comment: You don't need to create the anonymous object here, forget the comprehension expression: `rootNodes.ToDictionary(n => n.Name, n => n.Value)`.

Comment: ouch Richard, you beat me to it.

Comment: This (new) approach is good, but if it would be a very large object (or xml) it's not very efficient. I assume the author used the "select new" to optimize the query a bit. Also, change the v.Value to v.TagValue.

Comment: this still does not compile. you need to finally fix the spelling of `Dictionary`, and `XElement` doesn't have a `TagName` property.

Answer (score 0):

Use either
In this example you must ensure that the TagName is converted to string

```
Dictionary<string, string> allItems = (from n in rootNodes
select new
            {
                TagName = n.Name,
                TagValue = n.Value
            }).ToDictionary(v => v.TagName.ToString(), v => v.TagValue);
```

Or store the XName as key

```
Dictionary<XName, string> allItems = (from n in rootNodes
select new
            {
                TagName = n.Name,
                TagValue = n.Value
            }).ToDictionary(v => v.TagName, v => v.TagValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var element = xmlDoc.Root.Element("Cities");
            if (element != null)
            {
                var idList = element.Descendants().Where(p_ => p_.Name == "Name").Select(v_ => v_.Value).ToArray();
                var valList = element.Descendants().Where(p_ => p_.Name == "Population").Select(v_ => v_.Value).ToArray();

                var citiesDictionary = idList.Zip(valList, (key_, value_) => new { k = key_, v = value_ }).ToDictionary(x_ => x_.k, x_ => x_.v);
```